# Generate specific number of entities to a concrete time point in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

The problem is following: We want to simulate for 24 seconds. At every second except the 9th, 14th and 17th, the Entity-Generator must generate random number of entities e.g. between 1 and 3. For the concrete seconds (9th, 14th and 17th), the number of entities, generated at the same time, must be 5.

I'm thinking of taking the digital time block and adding some if-statements for the concrete seconds. But in this way, I will have the numbers of the entities at every simulation point. How can I then give this number to the generator as a parameter?

Is there also a simpler idea than mines?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the parameters of the random number generator during simulation. Easiest option is to use two random number generators and select the right one via if action.

I count 2 Action Subsystems with a generator each, the IF, Clock and a Merge. Doesn't sound too complicated.

Comment: You mean 2, one for the concrete times and one for the random?

Comment: Additional question: If a make these two subsystems - each with clock, if, and entity generator, then I can merge the generated entities and put them in a queue?

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the plan, try it and feel free to ask if you experience any problems.